# Deleting rows with constraint on indexed column (non unique) mySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm not very experienced with databases and don't want to mess up. Will be great if get some help.

Running mySQL 5.7 (InnoDB)

Indices of interest:

- column_1 -> unique index (primary index)
- column_2 -> non unique index
- column_3 -> non unique index

```
Want to delete all rows with column_2 value 'randomString'

Command:
delete from mydb.myTable
where column_2 = 'randomString'
```

- number of rows where column_2 = `randomString` = 2k
- total number of rows in the table = 400K

There's a system `System2` continuously reading from this DB looking for rows with `column_3` value `readValue`

- number of rows where `column_2` = `randomString` and `column_3` = `readValue` = 1.8K

**Questions**

Which rows will the delete statement mentioned above lock ? Is it only the rows with `randomString` ? In which case, will it also block the connections trying select * with constraint on column_3 till the lockwait timeout ?

or

What is the best way to safely delete the rows which have column_2 as randomString without blocking `System2` ??

Answer (score 1):

That delete will lock all 2K rows until it is finished, which might be a noticeable length of time.

Here are several tips on how to do big deletes with less impact.  (You have not provided enough details for me to point to a specific suggestion.)
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig